# After WCFService call End Further code does not execute on Client side

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to show a  message box on client side When a call is returned from service.

It is confirmed service runs and saves data into Database but call does not return.

I Google it but did not find a way

Here is my client code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                string ide = txt_id.Text;
                int id = int.Parse(ide);
                string city = txt_city.Text;

                Service1Client client = new Service1Client();

                if (client.insert(id, city))
                {
                    client.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Your changes were saved");

                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

Service code

```
public bool insert(int id,string city)
{
    Ship s = new Ship
    {
        order_id = id,
        shipcity = city,
        order_date = DateTime.Now
    };
    ShipsDataContext od = new ShipsDataContext();
    od.Ships.InsertOnSubmit(s);
    try
    {

        od.SubmitChanges();

        Console.ReadKey();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: please indent each code line with 4 extra spaces to have the syntax colouring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are waiting for console input:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

Btw, that error handling is a problem because you are suppressing bugs (by discarding all error information) and in case of error you do nothing.